# JQuery select by ID vs document.GetElementByID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just starting with JQuery and am working through a tutorial vid.  At one point the presenters go for javascript instead of a JQuery selector.  Just wondering why the javascript getElementById below works fine when passing an object to a function, but the second one doesn't?

Thanks!

```
// works
addTask(document.getElementById('taskText'), evt);

// doesn't
addTask($('#taskText'), evt);
```

Comment: Now we need to guess what's in the `addTask`, right?

Comment: My thought was that it didn't make a difference - it accepts an object and an event. I could post it though.

Comment: obviously if your function does accept one object and doesn't accept another - then issue is with the function ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getElementById()` returns a DOM element reference.

jQuery's selector returns a jQuery object. You can get the element reference from the jQuery object using

```
$('#taskText').get(0);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: Thanks for that.  I didn't know there was a difference between DOM and Jquery objects.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answer, regarding the result, if you want to use jQuery (which is easier to read), you can get the dom node directly like so:

```
addTask($('#taskText')[0], evt);
```

Comment: +1 Forgot about that one. It's also mentioned on the `get()` page

Answer (score 1):

`$('#taskText')` returns a jQuery object reference.

`document.getElementById('taskText')` returns a DOM element reference.

If your `addTask()` function doesn't know how to convert them to what it needs, then that would be the issue since one of them will need a conversion.

If you want to get the first DOM element reference from the jQuery object, you can do so with this:

```
$('#taskText').get(0)
```

So these two should be identical:

```
$('#taskText').get(0)
document.getElementById('taskText')
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are not exactly same

```
document.getElementById('taskText'); //returns a HTML DOM Object

var contents = $('#taskText');  //returns a jQuery Object

var contents = $('#taskText')[0]; //returns a HTML DOM Object
```

so you have to change it to get HTML Dom Object

```
addTask($('#taskText')[0], evt);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Phil and @jfriend00 have pointed out, document.getElementById('taskText') is a DOM element, and $('#taskText') is a jQuery object. The latter is an object of all DOM elements that match the selector.

Think of it as a zero based array, you could pass in the DOM element by doing this:

```
addTask($('#taskText')[0], evt);
```

Comment: Just guessing here but all your answer does is backup other answers. It might as well be a comment that says "+1"

Comment: Those comments weren't posted when I wrote this. Maybe I'll give them a +1 for faster typing skills ;)

Comment: Not sure about the downvote but the zero based array thing is helpful I think.  I guess .get(0) and the direct [0] reference do the same thing?

Comment: @Procrammer But you've referred to them directly in your answer

Comment: @Phil, Yeah before their edits. There was no reference to $('#taskText')[0] when I typed that. Gotta be quick on this site I see

Comment: @Glinkot, yes they do the same thing. Reference the first DOM element in the jQuery object.